# How do I get font name that is in use from command line?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I'm aware that Properties window gives the font name that is in use.

[image]

Is there a way to get that info from command line?

Comment: I don't think you can, You can change the font through cmd but that would require adding a key to registry.

Comment: `GetCurrentConsoleFont` Function https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getcurrentconsolefont will get this. For a similar program (for colour) that you may adapt see  https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/12/getconsolecolourexe-prints-current.html